# Xpath, How to select elements with a specific attribute?

Tags: xpath, nsindexpath

I am learning xpath and I am trying to get some data from html using xpath.
How do I select elements "A Number" with C contain C1>1 and Price<20

I want to select the elements:

```
<A Number=1234 Date=05-25-2007> 
<A Number=1235 Date=05-26-2007>
<A Number=1237 Date=05-25-2007>



    <A>
       <A Number="1234" Date="05-25-2007">
          <B>
             <B1>Judith Miller</B1>
             <Tax N="Yes" Rate="21"/>
          </B>
          <C>
             <C1 x="xxxxx" Price="20"/>
             <C1 x="yyyyy" Price="15"/>
          </C>
       </A>
       <A Number="1235" Date="05-26-2007">
          <B>
             <B1>Herbert Marshall</B1>
             <Adress Street="Saint Marc 2250" City="Oslo"/>
             <Tax N="Yes" Rate="21"/>
          </B>
          <C>
             <C1 x="yyyy" Price="25"/>
             <C1 x="zzzz" Price="12"/>
             <C1 x="xxxx" Price="22"/>
          </C>
       </A>
       <A Number="1236" Date="05-26-2007">
          <B>
             <Nazwa>Judith Miller</Nazwa>
             <Adress Street="Kennedy 511" City="Florida"/>
             <Tax N="Yes" Rate="21"/>
          </B>
          <C>
             <C1 x="fffff" Price="15"/>
          </C>
       </A>
       <A Number="1237" Date="05-25-2007">
          <B>
             <B1>Harrison Faber</B1>
             <Adress Street="Street 326" City="London"/>
             <Tax N="No" Rate="0"/>
          </B>
          <C>
             <C1 x="xxx" Price="20"/>
             <C1 x="yyy" Price="9"/>
          </C>
       </A>
    </A>
```

What is the XPath expression for selecting this elements?
Cheers

Comment: What does `C1>1` mean? Also, "Price" and "Cena" are different attributes in XML.

Comment: `<Tax=` is not a well-formed XML.

Comment: Thx! I correct "Price", "Cena" and <Tax.

Comment: C1>1 mean - I want select element A contains C1 more than one.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your data to be well-formed and uniform, I was able to get the three A's with

```
//A[count(C/C1) > 1][C/C1/@Price < 20]
```

Fixed data:

```
<root>
  <A Number="1234" Date="05-25-2007">
    <B>
      <B1>Judith Miller</B1>
      <Tax due="Yes" Rate="21"/>
    </B>
    <C>
      <C1 x="xxxxx" Price="20"/>
      <C1 x="yyyyy" Price="15"/>
    </C>
  </A>
  <A Number="1235" Date="05-26-2007">
    <B>
      <B1>Herbert Marshall</B1>
      <Adress Street="Saint Marc 2250" City="Oslo"/>
      <Tax due="Yes" Rate="21"/>
    </B>
    <C>
      <C1 x="yyyy" Price="25"/>
      <C1 x="zzzz" Price="12"/>
      <C1 x="xxxx" Price="22"/>
    </C>
  </A>
  <A Number="1236" Date="05-26-2007">
    <B>
      <B1>Judith Miller</B1>
      <Adress Street="Kennedy 511" City="Florida"/>
      <Tax due="Yes" Rate="21"/>
    </B>
    <C>
      <C1 x="fffff" Price="15"/>
    </C>
  </A>
  <A Number="1237" Date="05-25-2007">
    <B>
      <B1>Harrison Faber</B1>
      <Adress Street="Street 326" City="London"/>
      <Tax due="No" Rate="0"/>
    </B>
    <C>
      <C1 x="xxx" Price="20"/>
      <C1 x="yyy" Price="9"/>
    </C>
  </A>
</root>
```